# Add a user/author field formatter

Tags: 7, entities

i have a site where I use display suite for custom page display. And all works. Now I need to add a custom field formatter for the "Author" field, but I don't find how to link "author" to a new field formatter.

I know that I need to use hook_field_formatter_info() but I don't understand which is the right value for "field types". I have tried with "user", "user_reference", "text","author" but nothing.

I have tried to see how Display Suite define its fields formatter, but for this field the module use "2" for this value:

```
$fields['node']['author'] = array(
    'title' => t('Author'),
    'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION,
    'function' => 'ds_render_author_field',
    'properties' => array(
      'formatters' => array(
        'author' => t('Author'),
        'author_linked' => t('Author linked to profile')
      ),
    ),
  );
```

where

```
define('DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION', 2);
```

So how can I add one new field formatter for the author field ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info_alter/7 ?

Comment: @drupality: field api permit me to create a NEW field type. I want to formatter an existing field.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: I have to create a new display suite formatter because that page use ds for the display.

I have read this:

[Creating custom display suite fields or how I learned to stop worrying and use hook_ds_fields_info()](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/creating-custom-display-suite-fields-or-how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-use-hook-ds-fields)

and I have created my formatter. All works. Thanks for all to all.

Comment: Page not found.

Comment: https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/creating-custom-display-suite-fields-or-how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-use-hook-ds-fields